# Replace function has no effect

Tags: replace, vbscript

So the problem I am having right now is Replace function having no effect. The code is

```
param = WScript.Arguments(0)
param=Replace(param, "б", "vb")
MsgBox(param)
```

The second parameter is a cyrillic character (which I suspect could be the reason), yet I don't get any errors. It's just the output is literally the same as the input regardless of whether that `б` character occurs in the input or not

Comment: This is mainly because of the character encoding. If you paste the above example in a notepad and then save the vbs but with Encoding selected as "Unicode" then it will work as expected.

Comment: Tested with Vbsedit, worked fine for me. What are you passing as an argument? Have you checked the input first using `MsgBox(param)` before the `Replace()`?

Comment: Tested using a bat file to call vbs with command line param and it is working. Are you trying to run the vbs directly from command prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this problem occured was encoding indeed: changing UTF-8 to UTF-16 solved the problem without any further manipulations